# How to embed python variable on html

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need some help embedding python variables in html. I cant find a way of working without a framework like django or webpy.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding python variables in html"?

Comment: This requires server-side scripting. Naturally, frameworks and MVC's like Django comes to mind since it's the common way of doing such a thing. HTML doesn't support embedded python code, it's the other way around; python handles the HTML.

Comment: tried cgi?its boring,old and deprecated,yet looks like what you want..

Comment: This is what I mean by embedding
//html side
<body> var <body>
//Python side
var = 'Hello World'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) independently of the framework.

Read ["The Django template language: For Python programmers"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/), specifically the section on ["standalone mode"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#configuring-the-template-system-in-standalone-mode), for instructions on how to use just the template system.